# How to use External MIC with Laptop Speakers ON on Lenovo L340 Laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, microphone, speakers

I have Lenovo L340 laptop, it has one combo jack for audio & mic. I got one converter has one female combo port at one end and on the other side two males one for mic and one for audio.

I want to use external mic with my laptop speakers ON. But when I connect this combo jack to laptop, my laptop speakers are going OFF. How do I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the speaker in your task bar to adjust volume, the device name you are using will show up on top. My current device is NVIDIA. Click the device name to see a list of available devices that you can use to play sound.

[image]